# node js/jade error in css

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am trying to study node js. I converted a template to node js and it shows somme css problems. In the template there are social media icons of width = 30 px and padding 3px and border radius of 50%. It shows as a perfect circle in the original theme. But shows as ellipse in the node js converted theme.
here is the css code

```
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #e1e1e1;
font-size: 12px;
```

the converted theme works perfect when i change the padding to 9px. But i need to know wht this is happening. I tested this in google chrome. Please help.

the 1st one is from the original theme and the second one is from the node converted theme

[image: original theme icon][image: edited theme icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a perfect circle, the width and height of the element have to be exactly the same. I made an example http://jsbin.com/fuxen/1/edit where I set the height: to 30px to match the height.

Furthermore I added text-align: center and a line-height: of 30px (to center the "f" vertically).

Comment: i know this way... but i converted the theme using node js. There it shows error. Because of that i asked this question. Any way thank u for the help.. :)